# Google Extension and PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to include a PHP file inside a Google Extension? If so, how do I do it?

Here's my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My very first extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "My first extension",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://jquery.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "popup" : "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

So I have jQuery included and it seems to be working, so in my index.html I have this javascript:

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  async: false
 }).responseText;
```

Is there a way to include ajax.php and query it?

This is my first one, forgive me if this is a simple problem, but Google doesn't seem to produce any topics on this one,

Thanks!

Comment: in this example you are **NOT** including the `.php` file, it is being called by the ajax js function.

Comment: yep so the question is how to include it

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding, you DON'T include PHP into Javascript, unless your PHP script IS javascript code, and then I would ask WHY you have JS inside of a PHP script?

Comment: im talking about including into my extension package, so that I can use it, please read the question

Comment: You can include php file and read it from javascript as a text file, you can't run that php code though.

Comment: hmm interesting, thats what I needed to know, thanks serg i can mark is as correct if u answer it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put php file into extension folder and read it from javascript as a text file (from a background page), you can't run that php code though.