# Chrome Extensions: Using a Local PHP file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Popup.js is passing a value to my local php file for processing then the results are displayed on popup.html as shown below:

```
$.get("get_charities.php", {scope: "ALL", m_val: formatted_val},function(charity_arr){
        $('#convertor_content .result').remove();
        console.log(charity_arr);
        for(var i in charity_arr){
            $('#convertor_content').append( "Enough to "+ charity_arr[i].pre_text+" <a href='" + charity_arr[i].url + "' target='_blank'>" + Math.round(charity_arr[i].impact_value) + " " + charity_arr[i].post_text + "</a>" + "<br>" + "<hr>" );
        }
    });
```

Since I am using a local php file, how do I test if my popup.html is working correctly?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Chrome doesn't interpret PHP, you should have a local web server with php running and access it via `"http://localhost/get_charities.php"` URL.

Comment: also not clear how you will install the local server on every user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Extension and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878433/google-extension-and-php)